# How to style array elements separately

Tags: javascript, css

I have recently taken up programming and my first task is to create a queue at the post office. The code kind of works and does everything I need, except, I need the input array elements to be displayed with some style, more like separate squares with names (similarly to the way the buttons are styled), not only in line separated by commas - see the demo below please.

```js
var guests = new Array(); 

for (var i=0;i<10;i++){  
    guests[i] = prompt("Enter your name");
    if (guests[0] == null) {
       alert("No guests in a queue");
       break;
    } else if (guests[i] == null) {
       break; 
    } else {
       document.getElementById("queue").innerHTML=guests;
    }
} 
function removePeople() {
  guests.shift();
  document.getElementById("queue").innerHTML=guests;
  }
  
function reversePeople() {
  guests.reverse();
  document.getElementById("queue").innerHTML=guests;
  }
```

```css
button:hover {
background-color:beige;
color:black;
}

.button {
  background-color: green;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius:4px;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
}
```

```html
<body>

<p id="queue"></p>

<button class="button" onclick ="removePeople()">Next</button>

<button class="button" onclick ="reversePeople()">Reverse</button>

</body>
```

I tried hard to find some hints here but everything seems too complicated for my level of understanding. So, if there is no easy way, I would rather ask for some specific materials where I could find how to deal with it. I am learning through W3Schools and also reading Eloquent Javascript publication, but coulnd't find anything concerning my problem. I hope my question makes sense.
Also, if you have any idea how to logically improve the code, I am open to any discussion.

Comment: p tag is basically for text, to display , you can use div, and for each item in array, you can create a span with custom css/class and display it then

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to keep your code mostly the same.
To be able to change the css of a single queue item you need to wrap that item in something (in this example i've used a `span`)

I've created a function `createQueueItemsHtml()` that returns the array items wrapped in a `span` now you can use the following css selector to add css to each item `#queue span`

```js
var guests = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var guestInput = prompt("Enter your name");
  if(guestInput != "") {
    guests[i] = guestInput;
  }

  if (guests[0] == null) {
    alert("No guests in a queue");
    break;
  } else if (guests[i] == null) {
    break;
  } else {

    document.getElementById("queue").innerHTML = createQueueItemsHtml();
  }
}

function removePeople() {
  guests.shift();
  document.getElementById("queue").innerHTML = createQueueItemsHtml();
}

function reversePeople() {
  guests.reverse();
  document.getElementById("queue").innerHTML = createQueueItemsHtml();
}

function createQueueItemsHtml() {
    let queueString = "";
    for (var ii = 0; ii < guests.length; ii++) {
      queueString += "<span>" + guests[ii] + "</span>";
    }
    return queueString;
}
```

```css
button:hover {
  background-color: beige;
  color: black;
}

.button {
  background-color: green;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
}

#queue span {
  background-color: green;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<p id="queue"></p>

<button class="button" onclick ="removePeople()">Next</button>

<button class="button" onclick ="reversePeople()">Reverse</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. Only one thing, when you click on the Next or Reverse button, a new "null" element pops up next to other elements of an array. Do you have any idea how does it do this?

Comment: Where do you see this? in the `guests` array?

Comment: Yes, also in your code. If you input only two elements and click Next or Reverse, the third element named "null" pops out.

Comment: I've edited the code so that when the input field is left empty no array item is created

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working either. Anyway, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your guests into `<div>` elements and then style those in any way you want or need. (I haven't touched the rest of your code, only the part that was needed for this particular thing)

Just change this bit

```
else {
   document.getElementById("queue").innerHTML=guests;
}
```

To this:

```
} else {
        var guest = document.createElement('div');
        guest.classList.add('guest');
        guest.innerHTML = guests[i];
        document.getElementById("queue").appendChild(guest);
    }
```

What it does is create a `<div>` element for each item in your guests array, add `class="guest"` to the element and add the name from your prompt to it. Then it appends this element to the `#queue`.

Your HTML would then look like this:

```
<p id="queue">
    <div class="guest">john</div>
    <div class="guest">doe</div>
</p>
```

I would suggest changing the `<p>` to `<section>` or something like that, just for the sake of semantics.

You can then style these elements like this:

```
.guest { 
        
}
```

```js
var guests = new Array();

    for (var i=0;i<10;i++){
        guests[i] = prompt("Enter your name");
        if (guests[0] == null) {
            alert("No guests in a queue");
            break;
        } else if (guests[i] == null) {
            break;
        } else {
            var guest = document.createElement('div');
            guest.classList.add('guest');
            guest.innerHTML = guests[i];
            document.getElementById("queue").appendChild(guest);
        }
    }
```

```css
        guest:hover {
            background-color:beige;
            color:black;
        }
        
        .guest {
            background-color: green;
            border: 2px solid black;
            border-radius:4px;
            color: white;
            padding: 5px 15px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 16px;
            margin: 4px 2px;
            display: inline-block
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="queue"></p>
</body>
</html>
```